# How to populate data in dynamically created selectbox in a table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot

I have one service which gives me lots of Data from back-end. I have to show that in a table using jquery. 
I shows every data but unable to show the materialDetails in a selectbox. 
Could anyone help me on this ?

```
 $.each(response.data[0].listRawItemDetails, function (i) {
                            $("#received_item > tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                                        "<td>" + '<input type="hidden" name="fabricId'+i+'" value="'+response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].fabricId+'">'+ response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].fabriceCode + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td>" + '<input type="hidden" name="measurementRange'+i+'" value="'+response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].measurementRange+'">'+ response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].measurementRange + ' ' +response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].measurementType+ "</td>" +
                                                        "<td>" + '<input type="text" name="rate_'+i+'" id="rate_'+i+'" class="form-control rateCheck" value="" placeholder="Per '+response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].measurementType+'" style="width: 100px;" required="required">'+"</td>" +
                                                        "<td>" + '<span class="totalAmt'+i+'"></span>' + "</td>" +
                                                        **"<td>" + '<select class="form-control" id="materialDetails'+i+'"><option value="">-Select-</option></select>' + "</td>" +**
                                                    "</tr>");
                    }) //foreach
```

From **response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].meterials** I'm getting list of materials, I need to show that data, in last table data as a selectbox for each row.

Comment: Please explain your problem more briefly and post your all code that you have done yet.

Comment: I want to show the details coming from   response.data[0].meterials (It's a List)  inside #materialDetails select box

Comment: `response.data[0].listRawItemDetails` and `response.data[0].meterials` are not same.

Comment: Both are different

Comment: That is what I am trying to say, `meterials` has the data but you are using `listRawItemDetails` in the code!

Comment: From response.data[0].listRawItemDetails and from response.data[0].meterials I need data. But In the last data of each table row It should come from response.data[0].meterials.

Comment: Is it possible to add another foreach loop inside that ?

Comment: If it is response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[i].meterials is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I added these lines of code it works for me..

```
$.each(response.data[0].listRawItemDetails, function (i) {
                        $.each(response.data[0].listRawItemDetails[0].meterials, function(index, value) {
                            $('#materialDetails'+i).append('<option value="' + value+ '">' + value+ '</option>');
                        });
                    }); //foreach
```